# GLSL Vertex Shader gives wrong results if I do not mention gl_Vertex

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am writing a shader to draw lines with a width, as an alternative to glLineWidth, which doesn't work above 1.0 with ANGLE, and I'd like my lines to have the same thickness on Windows. I am running on desktop OpenGL for now, though.

The vertex shader source is as follows

```
attribute vec3 a_startPosition;
attribute vec3 a_endPosition;
attribute float a_choice;
attribute float a_dir;
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;
uniform float u_width;
uniform vec2 u_viewDims;

void main()
{
    vec4 start = u_mvpMatrix*vec4(a_startPosition, 1.0);
    vec4 end = u_mvpMatrix*vec4(a_endPosition, 1.0);

    //gl_Vertex;

    vec2 slope = normalize(end.xy - start.xy);
    slope = vec2(slope.y, -slope.x);
    vec2 scale = u_width/u_viewDims;

    if (a_choice == 0.0)
        gl_Position = vec4(start.xy + a_dir*scale*slope.xy*start.w, start.zw);
    else
        gl_Position = vec4(end.xy + a_dir*scale*slope.xy*end.w, end.zw);
}
```

See that I have gl_Vertex, unused, commented out.

```
int width, height;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(m_window, &width, &height);

glUseProgram(m_shaders[Shader_WideLine]->id());
GLint shaderid = m_shaders[Shader_WideLine]->id();

GLint coloc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "Color");
GLint dimloc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "u_viewDims");
GLint widthloc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "u_width");
GLint mvploc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "u_mvpMatrix");
GLint modelviewloc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "u_modelview");
GLint projloc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderid, "u_projection");

GLint dirloc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderid, "a_dir");
GLint startloc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderid, "a_startPosition");
GLint endloc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderid, "a_endPosition");
GLint chloc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderid, "a_choice");

//////////
//Set Uniforms
//////////
glUniform1f(widthloc, 10);
glUniform2f(dimloc, width, height);
glUniform4f(coloc, 0.101f, 0.558f, 0.109f, 1.f);

glm::mat4 modelview;
glm::mat4 projection;
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, glm::value_ptr(modelview));
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, glm::value_ptr(projection));

glm::mat4 mvp = projection * modelview;
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvploc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));

int numpts = 4;
GLfloat v[4][3] = {
    {0,1,0},
    {0,0,0},
    {1,0,0},
    {1,1,0}
};
//////////
// Draw (attributes)
//////////
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP ); 

glNormal3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

for(int i=0; i<numpts-1; i++)
{
    glVertexAttrib3fv(startloc, v[i]);
    glVertexAttrib3fv(endloc, v[i+1]);

    glVertexAttrib1f(chloc, 0);

    glVertexAttrib1f(dirloc, -1.0f);
    glVertex3d(0,0,0);

    glVertexAttrib1f(dirloc, 1.0f);
    glVertex3d(0,0,0);

    glVertexAttrib1f(chloc, -1);
    glVertexAttrib1f(dirloc, -1.0f);
    glVertex3d(0,0,0);
    glVertexAttrib1f(dirloc, 1.0f);
    glVertex3d(0,0,0);

}

glEnd();
glUseProgram(0);
```

So I am trying to draw lines from (0,1,0) to (0,0,0) to (1,0,0) to (1,1,0) with a width of 10 pixels. In the following images is a wire cube 2x2x2 centered on the origin for reference.

When called as presented I get the unexpected result of this [image: Incorrect lines]

If I uncomment gl_Vertex; in the shader, so that it is unused but referenced, I get this expected result. [image: Correct lines]

What is the reason that this could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` is not a valid ES 2.0 vertex shader built-in variable.

You'll have to pass in your MVP via uniform.

Comment: Okay, I updated to pass in MVP via uniform, and added invoking code and pictures to describe what's wrong.